# Wrap text in Pycharm console

Tags: pycharm

Say I do dir(str). I want a wrapped list returned, not a single line that goes on forever. I am using pycharm community edition. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

View -> Active Editor -> Use Soft Wraps

Also refer to this link: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-3483?projectKey=PY&query=can

Settings | Editor, "Virtual Space" group, [x] Use soft wraps in console